# Isogeny to a semi-simple group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a split reductive group over a field of characteristic zero. Is there always an isogeny $G \to H \times T$ with $H$ semi-simple and $T$ a split torus ?

I have in mind the case of $\text{GL}_n$ where we have (if I am not mistaken) the isogeny : $$\text{GL}_n \to \text{PGL}_n \times \mathbf{G}_m,\;\; g \mapsto (\overline{g},\det(g)).$$

Maybe it's even true that there is always a morphism $G \to G^{ad} \times Z(G)$ but I only need the less precise result I asked above.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is connected? There is always a canonical isogeny to $G^{ad}\times G^{ab}$, where $G^{ab} = G/G^{der}$.

Comment: I am indeed assuming that $G$ is connected and your comment answers my question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Note that the structure of a connected ereductive group may be rather complicated, when $G$ isn't semisimple or a torus: for examole, $D_4$ has a center of order 4 but exponent 2 and therefore can be combined with a torus in a complicated way.   Even so, an isogeny of the sort mentioned by Pera is always possible.